# Have multiple tables, need to select a specific row and change the background color via CSS

Tags: html, css

So I want to select a specific table row and change the background color. I know I can code it via html. But I would rather do it through CSS. I tried giving the table row a class name, but it still wont change the background color. I'm trying to change the background of the class "update". https://jsfiddle.net/q0395cyc/

```
<table class="table3">
            <tbody>

                <tr class="update">
            <td >

                FUNDRAISING UPDATE: $2.5 million in commited capital
            </td>
        </tr>
```

Comment: @Farside This has not anything to do with JavaScript.

Comment: ah, @Gendarme, true. Haven't taken a look on tags, under the post. It's pure task on coding-slicing. Then could be solved via stylesheets only.

Comment: Fix your syntax errors in HTML first.

Comment: Each of your `<tr>`s has only one `<td>` within it. It looks like you are using these tables purely to do layout of your page — _this is the **wrong way** to approach it_.  Each place you use a table you could use a `<section>` and within that use `<div>` (or `<article>` etc) in place of your `<tr>`. Even without HTML5 elements, this would be done better using divs not tables.

Comment: I should have been more specific I'm designing this so its compatible for email apps. I heard you want to shy away from divs and new semantics because alot of the email apps get confused easily.

Answer (score 1):

<sup>First fix your HTML syntax errors (unclosed tbody, tables etc...)</sup>

`TR` are **not** meant for design. **Forget they exist.**
`TR`s are just a way to tell the browser where your `TD`s group spans/ends.
**Style the inner `TD` instead**

```
.update td {
   background: red;
}
```

Example trying to style TR:

```css
tr.styled{
  background:    red;  /* will become red but... don't. */
  border-radius: 10px; /* this will not work */
  padding:       10px; /* neither will this */
  /* neither many other styles here */
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr class="styled">
    <td>Special offer</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Styling inner `TD`:

```css
tr.styled td{
  background:    red;   
  border-radius: 5px;
  padding:       10px; 
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr class="styled">
    <td>Special offer</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: it's better to be specific in your case: `background-color: red;` ;)